# Sending AWS SES email with embedded image is not working?

Tags: amazon-web-services

For my application, I am writing an lambda function in python for sending email from AWS SES.

For this email I am trying to attach an embedded image, this image I am downloading from s3 bucket to Lambda tmp file and I am adding it into SES body using  "html content like (`"<img src='/tmp/Marketing6.png' alt= 'image not found'/>`") " for that particular image.

Here is the code for downloading the image from S3 bucket to Lambda tmp:

```
        fileName =None
        s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
        bucket =s3.Bucket('examplebucket')
        for obj in bucket.objects.all():
                photoFileNameData = obj.key
                fileName = str(base64.b64encode(obj.get()['Body'].read()))
                fileName = fileName[2:-1]                   
                print(fileName)

        photoDatainBytes = bytes(fileName, 'utf-8')        
        with open('/tmp/Marketing6.png ', "wb") as fh:
            fh.write(base64.decodebytes(photoDatainBytes))
        data = open('/tmp/Marketing6.png ', 'rb')
        print(data)
```

body text which i have given:

```
      BODY_TEXT = ("Dear "+PlayerID+",\r\n\r\n"
                        "<img src='/tmp/Marketing6.png' alt= 'image not found'/>"
                        )
       SUBJECT = "Player name has been created "
        try:
            response = client.send_email(
                Destination={
                    'ToAddresses': [
                        RECIPIENT,
                        ],
                        },
            Message={
                'Body': {
                    'Html': {

                        'Charset': CHARSET,
                        'Data': BODY_TEXT,
                    },
                    'Text': {
                        'Charset': CHARSET,
                        'Data': BODY_TEXT,
                    },

                },
                'Subject': {
                    'Charset': CHARSET,
                    'Data': SUBJECT,
                },
            },
            Source=SENDER

            )
```

The mail which i have received :
 [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muYwq.png)

Answer (score 1):

The image you are using has to have a full URL. e.g. https://yoururl.com/image.jpg

One common way which I used is to upload it to S3 and use the S3 url for that image.

Your lambda will be terminated after the request is fulfilled. Therefore the lambda won't have that image when you open the email.